# Typescript Casting error in Angular 2 / Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am writing a simple app in ionic 2 but I have a problem with the anc (Angular compiler) because when I run ionic serve it gives me the warning but the app runs on the browser normally, but when I try to build for my phone it breaks and the build process results an error.

```
  var tempResults: ResultModel = new ResultModel(currentOne.id, (me.res.length > 1) ? me.res[0] : me.res[0], (me.res.length > 1) ? me.res[1] : me.res[0], currentOne.question, currentOne.imagePath);
    console.log(localforage.hasOwnProperty('result'))
    localforage.getItem('results').then(data=> {
      var allResponses: Array<ResultModel> = new Array<ResultModel>();
      if (data != null) {

        var allResponses: Array<ResultModel> = <Array<ResultModel>>JSON.parse(data);
            allResponses.push(tempResults);
        localforage.setItem('results', JSON.stringify(allResponses));
      } else {
        allResponses.push(tempResults);
        localforage.setItem('results', JSON.stringify(allResponses));
      }
    });
```

The Line that triggers the error is :
      var allResponses: Array = >JSON.parse(data);

And the error is :

> ngc error: Error: Error at C:/Users/.../result-item.ts:23:52: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

And I am getting a type error in the compiler and I am starting to think that this might be a bug after all.

Comment: `.then((data: string) => {` maybe might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, json.parse() expects a string as input, I believe your data parameter is an object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Yes you are actually right :/ the thing is that it was running normally on the browser and parsing correctly. Thank you for the very very fast response!!